# TypeError: functions.database is not a function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to update or creat an object, but i have this  error :"TypeError: functions.database is not a function" on the registry of firebase function

this is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.actualizar = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const obj = request.body;
    const MAC = obj.MAC;

    functions.database().ref ('/sensores/{MAC}').update(obj).promise.then(() => 
     {
       console.log("UpDate Success");
       return req.status(200).send("ok");

    })
    .catch(() => {
      functions.database.ref('/sensores'). set(obj).promise.then(() =>{
          console.log ("Created Succces");
          return req.status(200).send("");


      })
      .catch(() =>{
         console.log("Error");
         return req.status(500).send("error");

      })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to query the database.  It's just used for building the function definition.  To query your database or other Firebase products, you need to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), or whatever SDK is normally used to do so.

For example, you will see lots of [official sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) that starts like this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');  // this is the Admin SDK, not firebase-functions
admin.initializeApp();
//  Then use "admin" to reach into Realtime Database, Firestore, Cloud Storage, etc.
```

Comment: So instead of: functions.database().ref('/sensores/{MAC}').update(obj).promise.then(() => {
       console.log("UpDate Success");
       return req.status(200).send("ok");