# Access Firebase Realtime database/Firestore from Cloud Function via Firebase Emulator

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I want to use a tool like postman or my react native app to call a Firebase Cloud function and get access to Authentication, Firestore, Storage or Realtime Database emulator from the cloud function. Only the Admin SDK seems to work but it doesn't connect to the data in the emulator.

**Emulator**

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://localhost:4000                │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator       │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Authentication │ localhost:9099 │ http://localhost:4000/auth      │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions      │ localhost:5001 │ http://localhost:4000/functions │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore      │ localhost:8080 │ http://localhost:4000/firestore │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Database       │ localhost:9000 │ http://localhost:4000/database  │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at localhost:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500
```

what I have

**index.js**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { queries } = require("../../utils");

exports.countries = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    const allCountries = await queries.getAllCountries();

    return allCountries;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error getting countries  :", error);
    return null;
  }
});
```

**queries.js**

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

exports.getAllCountries = async function getAllCountries() {
  console.log("getting all countries ");

  let result = [];

  await admin
    .database()
    .ref("Countries")
    .once("value")
    .then((data) => {
      let countries = data.val();

      countries = countries.map(({ countryId, name, emoji }) => {
        return {
          id: countryId,
          name,
          emoji,
        };
      });

      result.push(...countries);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error finding country name", error);
      return null;
    });

  return result;
};
```

What I need

(inside my `getAllCountries` function I would like to call the Realtime db emulator not admin which connects to the PROD database )

```
    const functions = require("firebase-functions");

    //call real time databse emulator
   // i would like this call to reach localhost:9000/realtimedatabase 
       const allCountries = await functions.database
          .ref("countries")
          .then((result) => {})
          .catch((err) => {});
    
        return allCountries;
```

I get an error which says `functions.database.ref` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are retrieving some data from Firebase Realtime Database Emulator, first make sure that you imported some data. You can visit this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_rtdb#import_and_export_data) about exporting and importing data to Firebase RTDB Emulator.

Sample command to start the emulator and import the data to RTDB:

```
firebase emulators:start --import=./dir
```

To confirm, you will receive a log like:

```
i  database: Importing data from /usr/local/username/home/username/application/dir/sample-rtdb.json
```

Regarding this error:

> functions.database.ref is not a function.

You can't use the `firebase-functions` only to access your database from function; `firebase-functions` is not enough to access the database. You need to use some SDK like Firebase Admin SDK and initialize it to access, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51936771/8753991). According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_rtdb#admin_sdks), if you are using Admin SDK and your code is running inside the Cloud Functions emulator, your project ID and other configuration will be automatically set when calling `initalizeApp`.

```js
// As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("restricted_access/secret_document");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: how do i specify to import to firestore or realtime database ?  I  used this command  firebase emulators:start --only auth,functions,firestore,database --import=./data and it always go to realtime database